# Understanding a combinatorial relation.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I would like some insight as to why the following expression is true.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n {{n}\choose{i}} 2^{n-i} = 3^n $$

I arrived at this relation in solving a subset problem, and I understand the left hand side in terms of a combinatorial approach to said problem. However, I am having trouble interpreting the right hand side as an equivalent expression, both logically (from a combinatorics perspective) and mathematically.

Comment: What do you mean by "interpreting the right hand side as an equivalence?" That seems vague.

Comment: Apart from understanding that this is true mathematically, I wanted to understand how both sides could solve the same problem from a logical perspective.

Comment: What is the difference between understanding something logically and mathematically? I'm not trying to be mean, but, as you can see, one person answered your question using Binomial theorem, and another with a combinatorial argument.

Comment: Yup - these responses were exactly what I needed. :) I can't choose an answer for a few minutes, though. Pardon the nuance in semantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$3^n=(1+2)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\cdot 1^{i}\cdot 2^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\cdot 2^{n-i}.$$

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the mathematical insight! I saw the $(1+2)^n$ decomposition and d'ohed.

Comment: @JTCho: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways that we can color $n$ objects either green, blue, or purple, is equal to the number of ways that we can first select $k$ objects to be green (for arbitrary $k$, $0\leq k \leq n$), then color the rest blue or purple.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for in terms of a combinatorial approach. Thanks. :)